# session id automatically appending to href incorrectly in PHP with json_encode

Tags: php, json, session

I've disabled use of cookie and enabled **session.use_trans_sid**.
The code snippet below is returning a **JSON string**. PHP is automatically appending **session Id** incorrectly to the href attribute in the json string which results in an **invalid JSON**

```
<?php
ini_set('session.use_cookies', 0);
ini_set('session.use_only_cookies', 0);
ini_set('session.use_trans_sid', 1);
ini_set('session.name', 'SID');

session_start();
header('Content-Type:application/json');
$test = ["test" => '<a href="https://maps.google.com">testlink</a>'];
echo json_encode($test);
?>
```

**response**

```
{"test":"<a href=\?SID=absd8765gjjgjgj5c2fjro6ucbcsc1ekjaah3"https:\/\/maps.google.com\">testlink<\/a>"}
```

OS: Linux
PHP: 5.4

Comment: Hope my post will help you out.

Answer (score 0):

You should create the **array** first with correct quotes then convert them to JSON string.

`$test = array("test" => "<a href='https://maps.google.com'>testlink</a>");
echo json_encode($test);`

and that random string is converting quotes to json while encoding

else try this your code but quotes are corrected

```
ini_set('session.use_cookies', 0);
ini_set('session.use_only_cookies', 0);
ini_set('session.use_trans_sid', 1);
ini_set('session.name', 'SID');

session_start();
header('Content-Type:application/json');
$test = ["test" => "<a href='https://maps.google.com'>testlink</a>"];
echo json_encode($test);
```

Answer (score 0):

Try this hope it will work.

[**PHP code demo**](https://eval.in/770889)

**Change this to:**

```
 echo json_encode($test);
```

**This:**

```
echo json_encode($test,JSON_HEX_QUOT|JSON_PRETTY_PRINT);
```

`JSON_PRETTY_PRINT` is optional

```
<?php
ini_set('session.use_cookies', 0);
ini_set('session.use_only_cookies', 0);
ini_set('session.use_trans_sid', 1);
ini_set('session.name', 'SID');

session_start();
header('Content-Type:application/json');
$test = ["test" => '<a href="https://maps.google.com">testlink</a>'];
echo json_encode($test,JSON_HEX_QUOT|JSON_PRETTY_PRINT);
```